# Can I use existing .tfw (of georeferenced .tif images) as the extent in a MapServer Mapfile?

Tags: mapserver, georeferencing, mapfile

I have a set of aerial georeferenced tiff and tfw files, I want to be able to access them using MapServer.

Now the mapfile requires an `EXTENT` parameter with coordinates which i think they are already specified in the .tfw I was hopping for something like this

```
MAP
  IMAGETYPE      PNG
  EXTENT         "0232BC_23.tfw"
  SIZE           400 300
  IMAGECOLOR     255 255 255

    LAYER
        NAME "0232BC_23"
        DATA "0232BC_23.tif"
        TYPE RASTER
         STATUS ON
    END
END
```

any idea to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the EXTENT in that way.

EXTENT is expecting a string of minx miny maxx maxy values, like:

```
EXTENT -8.6476 49.8639 1.76943 60.8622
```

You can use gdalinfo to get the extents of your raster file:

```
gdalinfo /path/to/0232BC_23.tif
```

Comment: but i already have coordinates on my tfw files... can't i use them?

Comment: And the look ugly `0.500000000000000000
0.0
0.0
-0.500000000000000000
466365.91103273828
9729699.6079745516`

Comment: In the extent parameter you must explicitly state the extent values, you can't do it by reference in the way you are trying.

Comment: Do you have GDAL?

Comment: Yes i have Gdal

Comment: But i only used gdal2tiles to generate tiles... I now want to adopt a mapserver

Comment: The advice to use gdalinfo is good. You can't find extent from tfw files because it is only telling the coordinates of the top-left pixel and pixel sixe. That is not enough the finding the other corner because tfw file does not tell the width and height of the image in pixels.